# How to return an image object in django http response?

Tags: html, django, python-3.x, image, html-email

I am sending emails containing images. I am using html templates for these emails. I want the images to be generated on the fly. Hence, the '*src*' in the image tag is a url that makes a REST api call to my app. The images are dynamically created, a publicly accessible URL is created. I want this image to be displayed in the email. But I am not able to figure out how to return this image.

Comment: Just return an [`HttpResponse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-objects) from your view where the content-type header is set to image/jpeg (or whatever your image format is) and the `content` is your generated image.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want some code like this

```
    the_image= Image.new(#whatever you want in your image)
    response = HttpResponse(content_type="image/jpeg")
    the_image.save(response, "JPEG")
    return response
```